# Missing key error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I´m using google static map in a contact page and google are displaying an error in an alert box saying something like "Was unable to display Google maps in this page, please contact the site admin".

In the console it shows MissingKeyMapError and the solution seems pretty obvious but i have the very same site running in other domain and its working there.

I read that google changed their policies and they will no longer accept requests without key here https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update

Besides that i can use static map locally without a key

Answer (score 1):

All sites known before June 22, 2016 and localhost were "grandfathered", so you can continue to use API without the key there, but any new site created after June 22 requires an API key.

#### Update

Situation changed in June 2018. Google announced [Google Maps Platform](https://mapsplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/introducing-google-maps-platform.html) which requires API keys for all services. Now all web sites must implement API keys. "Grandfathering" will be removed within next months.